# Quartz Scheduler +HSQLDB huge .lobs file. size increasing forever

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, hsqldb

I'm using quartz 2.2.1 and HSQLDB 2.3.2 and 2.3.3 (I have tried with both of them).

I have 1 quartz job and 16 quartz triggers. The triggers fire very frequently (let say every second)
When a trigger fires quartz send a DELETE and a INSERT to the database instead of using UPDATE

Real Example obtained from the HSQLDB log:

```
/*C3974*/SET SCHEMA PUBLIC

DELETE FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS
  WHERE SCHED_NAME='monitORA' AND
  TRIGGER_NAME='CL1DEST1INF1PL1LIN7' AND
  TRIGGER_GROUP='grupoInformes'

INSERT INTO QRTZ_TRIGGERS
  VALUES('monitORA','CL1DEST1INF1PL1LIN7','grupoInformes',
         'informesSQL','group1',NULL,1432557642000,
         1432557639000,5,'ACQUIRED','CRON',
         1432556986000,0,NULL,1,978)

INSERT INTO QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS
  VALUES('monitORA','monitORA11432557151496','CL1DEST1INF1PL1LIN7',
         'grupoInformes','monitORA1',1432557641149,1432557642000,
         5,'ACQUIRED',NULL,NULL,FALSE,FALSE)

SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS

DELETE FROM LOB_IDS WHERE LOB_ID=978

INSERT INTO LOB_IDS VALUES(978,121,1,30)

COMMIT
```

In the qrtz_triggers table there is a BLOB column, and thats why HSQLDB internally executes delete and insert in LOB_IDS table......

The .lobs file is always increasing its size, although I execute checkpoint and checkpoint defrag......and this is a big problem in a non stop environment......
With this 1 job and 16 triggers after executing for 3-5 days the size of .lobs file is up 8GB (and growing)

Why a delete and an insert are executed instead of an update?

and How can avoid .lobs file increasing for ever?

Thank you very much

Comment: An UPDATE is translated into DELETE and INSERT statements. No new LOB is created in the .log snippet you report (changes to the LOBS table represent actual lob creation and removal). The .lobs file will grow if the application keeps the old records and adds new ones. It must be the way Quartz works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following command in the database using the manager tool (runManager.bat or runManagerSwing.bat):

```
CHECKPOINT DEFRAG
```

This command reclaims unused space in the database files.
If this does not help yet, then try the following:

```
SHUTDOWN COMPACT
```

This command shuts down the database, creates an insert script that is able to recreate the database, then executes it to recreate the database files, which is supposed to create "clean" database files from scratch.

See also:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_system_operations

Note that these commands might not work as expected for lobs in older HSQLDB versions.